# Populated query in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have two classes `table` and `recordset`. Table has a linkset of `recordset.` When I query any particular table,

```
select * from table where @rid=#17:0
```

I get response containing recordset array with ids

```
"recordsets": [
            "#20:0"
        ],
```

But I want the result as as an array of objects (expanded ones). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT from table where @rid=#17:0 FETCHPLAN *:-1
```